# Javascript / JQuery random images repeat issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, do-while, rotator

I have an image gallery which pulls in random images from the folder images/flip_images/. The files are names as a number then .jpg, e.g. 0.jpg, 1.jpg etc. There are 14 images which it can choose from, labelled 0 - 13. As there are only 14 images and the page needs 4 at a time, there is quite a bit of repeating, which I would like to avoid. I am using Javascript to generate the random image filenames and passing the variables into the JQuery .flip() command.

I have tried using the do while loop in the code below to change a global variable, compare the global variable to the others and pick another number if the number it chose in the first place is already in use. I can't, however, seem to get this to work. Is this a scope issue or have I just made a simple mistake in the code? Here is the code:

```
var randomNumber0= 0;
var randomNumber1= 1;
var randomNumber2= 2;
var randomNumber3= 3;

var refreshId0 = setInterval(function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    do {

        randomNumber0=Math.floor(Math.random()*14)

    }while(randomNumber0 == randomNumber1 || randomNumber0 == randomNumber2 || randomNumber0 == randomNumber3){

        randomNumber0=Math.floor(Math.random()*14)

    };

    $("#flipboxa").flip({       
        direction: 'lr',
        color: "transparent",
        content: '<img src="images/flip_images/'+randomNumber0+'.jpg" width="120" height="275" alt="alt tag here" />',
    });

    return false;

}, 5000);

var refreshId1 = setInterval(function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    do {

        randomNumber1=Math.floor(Math.random()*14)

    }while(randomNumber1 == randomNumber0 || randomNumber1 == randomNumber2 || randomNumber1 == randomNumber3){

        randomNumber1=Math.floor(Math.random()*14)

    };  

    $("#flipboxb").flip({       
        direction: 'rl',
        color: "transparent",
        content: '<img src="images/flip_images/'+randomNumber1+'.jpg" width="120" height="275"  alt="alt tag here" />',
    });

    return false;

}, 6000);

var refreshId2 = setInterval(function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    do {

        randomNumber2=Math.floor(Math.random()*14)

    }while(randomNumber2 == randomNumber0 || randomNumber2 == randomNumber1 || randomNumber2 == randomNumber3){

        randomNumber2=Math.floor(Math.random()*14)

    };

    $("#flipboxc").flip({       
        direction: 'lr',
        color: "transparent",
        content: '<img src="images/flip_images/'+randomNumber2+'.jpg" width="120" height="275" alt="alt tag here" />',
    });

    return false;

}, 7000);

var refreshId3 = setInterval(function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    do {

        randomNumber3=Math.floor(Math.random()*14)

    }while(randomNumber3 == randomNumber0 || randomNumber3 == randomNumber1 || randomNumber3 == randomNumber2){

        randomNumber3=Math.floor(Math.random()*14)

    };  

    $("#flipboxd").flip({       
        direction: 'rl',
        color: "transparent",
        content: '<img src="images/flip_images/'+randomNumber3+'.jpg" width="120" height="275"  alt="alt tag here" />',
    });

    return false;

}, 8000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** the proper form of a `do..while`

```
do {

    //something

}while(...){

    //something else

};
```

Try it like this:

```
do {
    //something
}
while(...);
```

Comment: @PhilFaceplantYoung happy to help :-D